# How to apply lambda function to clean column names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pipeline

I have a dataset with column names having typos say "Address %", "Unit ", I need to remove % and strip the white space

Simply below will work

```
X.columns = X.columns.str.replace('%', '')
X.columns = X.columns.str.strip()
```

But I have a pipeline class

```
class ApplyTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def fit(self, X,  y = None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = self.func(X)
        return X
```

Created a pipeline and used lambda function, but not working,

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('Remove %', ApplyTransformer(lambda X:  ['' if '%' in x else x for x in X.columns]  ))            
            ])
```

So how to write the lambda to do that operation?

Answer (score 0):

By "does not work", I think you mean the dataframe is gone and only the column names are coming out.

Try this:

```
def my_column_name_changer (X): 
    X.columns = ['' if '%' in x else x for x in X.columns]
    return X
pipeline = Pipeline([
            ('Remove %', ApplyTransformer(my_column_name_changer))            
            ])
```

Comment: Yes, you are very correct, only column name is coming, I tried with the function it works, but my issue is I want to save only pipeline without dependencies (but with generic classes), so I am not sure how where to have my methods?

Comment: You mean you want to pickle the pipeline ? (or joblib save?)